# consuming SOAP web serives in google app engine and GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am writing a web application in GWT,
I am trying to interact with a SOAP web service.
I know how to do it in regular java environment using the JAX-WS library, but GAE (Google App Engine) does not support it.

see http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine

is there a way of consuming a wsdl based web service (ebay web service for example) using GWT+GAE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google have now provided SOAP support for GAE:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html

Comment: can anyone provide me the new URL? this one is old and broken?

Comment: Find the source of it here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/docs/appengine/articles/soap.html?r=223 and the site as it was in 2012 in the WayBackMachine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120220232536/http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html

Comment: @AntonKaiser how can the above been achieved in android studio? am trying to run the script he is providing but it fails.

Comment: help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573829/how-to-send-and-receive-soap-data-from-webservice-to-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it seems to work with the `AxiomSoapMessageFactory` from [Spring WS.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites)

There is a detailed article named [Exposing SOAP Service on GAE](http://blog.cloudwhiz.com/2009/09/exposing-soap-service-on-gae-part-1.html). I assume it might be possible to consume one WS following the same technology stack [Using Spring Web Services on the Client](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html).

Comment: help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573829/how-to-send-and-receive-soap-data-from-webservice-to-google-app-engine