# Google App Engine + OpenCMIS

Tags: google-app-engine, soap, opencmis

Problem in SOAP connection From the GWT solution to CMIS webServer.

GWT 2.4.0

Google App Engine 1.7.3 is used.

Apache OpenCMIS 0.8 library is used.

i've looked in
[consuming SOAP web serives in google app engine and GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268474/consuming-soap-web-serives-in-google-app-engine-and-gwt) article.
And http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/soap.html. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5332

SOAP CMIS connection is made internaly in the Apache OpenCMIS library. (jaxws-rt-2.1.7.jar)

REST Atom Pub connection works nice.
I've got the following error, trying to connect to the SOAP webservice:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.ProxySelector is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress$1.run(EndpointAddress.java:153)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress$1.run(EndpointAddress.java:152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress.chooseProxy(EndpointAddress.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress.<init>(EndpointAddress.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parsePort(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:369)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseService(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:341)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:265)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.impl.jaxb.DiscoveryService.<init>(DiscoveryService.java:42)
```